# How to add an array size validation rule in an angularjs form?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a form with some text input fields and a dynamic list of items stored in the $scope of the controller, with some functions to add/remove items in the list.
I want to invalidate the form until the items list reaches a predefined length.

So I created a formRepeat directive which takes a ngModel attribute and then use the ngModelController to invalidate the form.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jSFvak?p=preview

This works but I think it's not the better way to do that as the directive is not very flexible.

The easiest would be to invalidate the form in the controller with something like :

```
$scope.myForm.$valid = false;
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JUvAge?p=preview). I'd use the following `$watch` function (similar to @NicolasMoise response)

```
$scope.$watch('items', function (items) {
    $scope.myForm.$setValidity('count', items.length >= 5);
}, true);
```

It's important to set the `objectEquality` flag to `true` so that the `$watch` will fire if any of the objects properties change

or, if only a shallow list (collection) comparison is made, use `$watchCollection`

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function (items) {
    $scope.myForm.$setValidity('count', items.length >= 5);
});
```

I've also never had any luck with `$setValidity('$valid')` or similar

Comment: Good idea to create a new 'error key', seems to be the cleanest way to handle this. Thanks !

Comment: how would you turn this into a custom validator?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for me was to target array's length as hidden number `input` and put `min` validation on it. Very clean solution, in fact.

```
<input style="display: none;" type="number" name="itemsCount" ng-model="items.length" min="{{min}}">
```

Check out the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BoVOKj2JhucFFuCbGcUJ?p=preview)

Comment: This answer is easy, elegant and quick to implement - need to add 'required' attribute Brother.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do so (IMO) is to create a custom directive that uses the [ngModelController Validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators).

Validators get executed every time there is an update on the model and are used for form validity.
Your directive may look something like this:

```
angular.module('directiveTest', []).directive('minLength', function() {
return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
  scope.minlength = attrs.minLength || 1;
  ngModel.$validators.minLength  = function(modelValue){
    /* Assume TRUE when empty, as ngRequired should be used for mandatory values */
    return (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue)) ? true : (modelValue.length >= scope.minlength);
  };
}
};
});
```

And can call it from your HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" name="content" ng-list min-length="2" ng-model="content" />
```

You can find the working example on the following [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQzp18gi7gksWG8OlXp0?p=preview).

Comment: this has one issue: when array length is decreased to zero from controller then array instance is actually deleted

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to use a directive in this case. Just have an ng-repeat for items and inside your **controller** something like this

```
$scope.$watch('items', function(val){
    if(val.length<5){
        //$scope.myForm should be available here
        $scope.myForm.setValidity('$valid');
        //add additional form validation ($dirty, setting back to $invalid, etc...)
    }
})
```

Comment: Tried it here [(see plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/JUvAge?p=preview).
Like this it doesn't do anything, if a replace the '<' with a '>' it does invalidate the form after 5 items have been added...
I didn't got any good result by replacing '$valid' by '$invalid'.
After some thinking, I don't think it's a good idea to validate the form itself in the controller, as it would 'shadow' all the other input fields validation rules...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is what your looking for http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Maybe I missed something but it seems we can only invalidate form controls with the form controller, not the form itself (setValidity only works on form controls). The problem is, I use ng-repeat to generate the DOM for the dynamic list stored as an array in the scope, so there isn't any form control I can use FormController on.

Comment: $scope.myForm should be available inside your controller. However, AFAIK you can't access inside directives (your own custom or inside ng-repeat)

Comment: You can also set validity for the entire form, not sure how it reacts when there are conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using ng-class.

Try this ,
In HTML,

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form name="myForm" ng-class="formClass">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" data-ng-model="user.country" class="form-control" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Items</label>
            <br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
            <p data-ng-show="items.length < min">I need at least {{min}} items ! (so {{min - items.length}} more would be good)</p>
            <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeItem($index)">Delete</button>
              <span>{{item}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In your script.js,

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.min = 5;
    var _counter = 0;
     $scope.formClass="invalid";
    $scope.addItem = function () {
      $scope.items.push('item' + _counter);
      _counter++;
     $scope.isFormValid();
    };
    $scope.isFormValid=function(){
       if ($scope.items.length < 5) {
        $scope.formClass="invalid";
      } 
      else if ($scope.items.length >=5){
         $scope.formClass="valid";
      }
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (index) {
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);  
      $scope.isFormValid();
    };

  }]);
```

In css file,

```
body {
  padding: 16px;
  background: #555555;
}

/*.my-form {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ffffea;
}*/

.invalid {
    transition:0.5s linear all;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ffffea;
  background: #ffeaea;
}

.valid {
    transition:0.5s linear all;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ffffea;
  background: #eaffea;
}
```

Do you want something like this?.

Please have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/98Yr9fgHVpNkeymsA3IX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. It's working but it's just a visual trick. What I try to do is to make the form itself aware that something is wrong, like any other form error.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but I do that like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
        ng-disabled="form.$invalid || user.groups.length == 0>
        Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working but it's just a visual trick like the other answer. What I try to do is to make the form itself aware that something is wrong, like any other form error (wrong input size, wrong email format, ...).